# D using emplace

Tags: d

I am trying to use emplace in this piece of code:

```
class motionFactory{
        public:
            this(double velocity, double gravity, double angle){
                this.velocity = velocity;
                this.gravity = gravity;
                this.angle = angle;
            }
            motion getMotion(double step) const{
                auto ptr = malloc(motion.sizeof);
                return emplace!motion(ptr, velocity, gravity, angle, step);
            }
        private:
            double velocity;
            double gravity;
            double angle;
    }

    class motion : motionFactory{
        public:
            this(double velocity, double gravity, double angle, double step){
                super(velocity, gravity, angle);
                this.current = 0;
                this.step = step;
                this.range = getCurrentRange();
            }
        private:
            double current;
            const double step;
            const double range;

    }
```

And I keep getting this singular compilation error.

```
error: template std.conv.emplace cannot deduce function from argument types !(motion)(motion, const(double), const(double), const(double), double), candidates are:
  102 |                 return emplace!motion(ptr, velocity, gravity, angle, step);
```

After looking at the documentation for too long with no avail, I'm at a loss.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by tinkering with the examples on the doc page for emplace.

```
size_t size = __traits(classInstanceSize, motion);
void[] ptr = malloc(size)[0..size];
return emplace!motion(ptr, velocity, gravity, angle, step);
```

This compiles and works just fine for me.
Fascinatingly enough keeping the cast there meant the D allocator would get called somewhere which would opens the door to allocator mixing.

Answer (score 0):

`emplace` takes as the first parameter not an *untyped* pointer, but a pointer typed as the thing to be emplaced.

That is one problem. The second problem is that `motion.sizeof` is going to be the size of the *class reference*, in other words, the size of a pointer. You want the size of the class data. To get this, you want to use `__traits(classInstanceSize, motion)`.

The `getMotion` function should be changed to:

```
            motion getMotion(double step) const{
                auto ptr = cast(motion)malloc(__traits(classInstanceSize, motion));
                return emplace(ptr, velocity, gravity, angle, step);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't think about the fact that all D variables are pointers so thank you for pointing out the bug with sizeof. Unfortunately however your solution to my core issue is something I did try and it did not work(did not compile with the same error). Luckily however I did find the real solution by working from the examples on the doc page for emplace

Comment: Note that all *class* variables are pointers, not all variables. Which is what I think you meant, but good to be clear. And it is weird that did not work for you, I copied that code directly from a test I ran that did compile. However, yes, you can use a void[] array to emplace, a void * does not work, which is probably why it thought you were trying to pass it as a constructor parameter.